# Workaround massive bool operation

Tags: texturing, modifiers, shaders, osl

I have this formation of objects. These are around 23.000 cylinders and a Sphere in the middel. I need to make a hole everywhere a cylinder intercepts with the sphere and then export this sphere to an object so I can print the Sphere with the holes in it. Since substracting 23.000 cylinders from a sphere is to much for my pc I need a work around. It would be very nice if you could help me. The cylinders are generated using multiple C# Scripts and the game Engine Unity it is then exported to an .fbx file and imported into Blender. I tryed blender since I know the program on a moderate base. If you have another suggestion for a programm which would do the job, I would be realy greatfull as well. What is most important for me is the result and I need it done for my studies.

Thank you very much[image]

Comment: Would joining all the cylinders by pressing `Ctrl` + `J` and then applying a single boolean operation help?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: It might be an option to get a texture from the sphere which can then be printed and glued to a Sphere so I can make a hole where its supposed to be. I mean physicly with a drill or smth. But for that I need the texture where the cylinders meet the sphere.

Comment: So far it only worked for fast bool. I have an object now, but I will experiment a little further for more precice results.